# RTF String To Image

Tags: image, javafx, richtext

I have to work with an already existing database. The photos are saved with rtf strings.

How do I convert the rtf string into a `javafx.scene.image.Image`?

How can I save a new picture in this rtf format?

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\qr\cf1\f0\fs16{\object\objemb{\*\objclass Paint.Picture}\objw1604\objh420{\*\objdata 
01050000
02000000
07000000
50427275736800
00000000
00000000
```

Comment: It is an OLE embedded Paint object.  [The RTF spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-10/aa140283(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#objects) won't help you decode it,  The MS Paint app decodes and encodes it and the RTF delegates to that (at least as I understand OLE).  I don't know how you will decode it.  You could (probably) write the data to a file, open the file in an RTF editor, copy and paste the image into Paint and save it from there in the desired format.  But that is a manual process, it won't scale if you have a lot of images (and it is one way).